# What's the best way to use global setting?

Tags: vuejs2

I wanna a vue component's prop has a global default value if its not setting. Follow bellow I use window['globalClasses'] to get the global setting. But I know in server side, window is not exists. So what's the best way to get the global setting.

```
export default {
  props: {
    classes: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return window['globalClasses'] || {};
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: What server-side language are you using? Also, do you mean to assign these settings from server response data?

Comment: You could also use vuex.